# Why my emulator is throwing me the error, missing system image?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle, android-emulator

Well, actually, I am a newbie to android. I have been trying to develop an app that has google maps, and everything was going fine until today when I got this error from the emulator.[image: Error message]

Here are some files in case it may be helpful.
Manifest XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.uaproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.UAProject">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Hotels"
            android:exported="true"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeScreen" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />

        <activity
            android:name=".NoteEditorActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeScreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutApp"
            android:exported="true"
            android:parentActivityName=".Menu" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Copyrights"
            android:exported="true"
            android:parentActivityName=".Menu" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ToAboutBayanOlgey"
            android:exported="true"
            android:parentActivityName=".Menu" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ToAboutUs"
            android:exported="true"
            android:parentActivityName=".Menu" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:exported="true"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeScreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreen"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle-app level

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.uaproject"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.3.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

build.gradle-root level

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1"
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

PS: By the way, if you guys have time, could you please guide me on how to add google maps to an already-created fragment(for example, my fragment is the one of a bottom navigation). I have been searching but all I tried did not work for some reason. Or just a link to the valid way would do because there seemed to be many obsolete approaches to this as well, which we beginners cannot really discern.